# Hamming Distance on binary Vector in Scala

Tags: scala, hamming-distance

I would like to have a fast implementation of Hamming distance on binary vectors.
I tested it on `Array[Byte]` rather than `Array[Int]` thinking that it would be faster but it's not the case.
If someone can explain me this behaviour and/or advise me on a better implementation.

```
def hammingDistanceI(v1:Array[Int], v2:Array[Int]) = {
  v1.zip(v2).count{case(a,b) => a!=b}
}
def hammingDistanceB(v1:Array[Byte], v2:Array[Byte]) = {
  v1.zip(v2).count{case(a,b) => a!=b} 
}

def speedMeasureByte(v:Array[Byte], nbIte:Int) = {
  val t0 = System.nanoTime
  for(i<-0 to nbIte-1) hammingDistanceB(v,v)
  val t1 = System.nanoTime
  (t1-t0)/1000000
}

def speedMeasureInt(v:Array[Int], nbIte:Int) = {
  val t0 = System.nanoTime
  for(i<-0 to nbIte-1) hammingDistanceI(v,v)
  val t1 = System.nanoTime
  (t1-t0)/1000000
}

val v1Int = Array.fill(100)(Random.nextInt(2))
val v1Byte = v1Int.map(_.toByte)

val (tInt, tByte) = (speedMeasureInt(v1Int,1000000),
                     speedMeasureByte(v1Byte,1000000))

// tInt = 1636 ms
// tByte = 3307 ms
```

Comment: The way I see it... you are running your measurements on a cold jvm. Warm up the jvm first and then look at the numbers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure why byte implementation is slower than the other, but suspect it has to do with the way `!=` is implemented - cpu registers are better equipped to deal with four-byte sequences nowadays than with single bytes.

The above is just my guess though, don't bet your house on it.

As for a faster implementation, if your use case is such, where single nanoseconds matter, you'll have to abandon the elegance of scala collections and stick with the old good loops:

```
 def hd(a: Array[Int], b: Array[Int]) { 
   var c = 0
   var i = 0
   while(i < a.length) { c += a(i)^b(i); i+=1 }
   c
 }
```

This should be several hundred times faster on average than your implementation.

Comment: Thank you, your implementation speed up the process by a factor 30. I also tested it with Array[Byte] but the gain is around 5% for Byte rather than Int.

Comment: 30 doesn't seem THAT impressive. In my benchmarks, it is about 300 times faster.

Comment: I don't know why but after new tests, i got a improvement of a factor 500. It is preferable to use Vector rather than Array or other kind of structure ?

Comment: i think, Array would be the fastest, provided that you loop through it directly, like I showed as opposed to `.mapp`'ing over it and using collections api. In the latter case, a `Seq` is, porbably, somewhat faster.